# Pandas interpolate NaNs from zero to next valid value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I am looking for a way to linear interpolate missing values (NaN) from zero to the next valid value.

E.g.:

```
     A    B   C   D  E
0  NaN  2.0 NaN NaN  0
1  3.0  4.0 NaN NaN  1
2  NaN  NaN NaN NaN  5
3  NaN  3.0 NaN NaN  4
```

Given this table, i want the output to look like this:

```
     A    B   C   D  E
0  NaN  2.0   0   0  0
1  3.0  4.0   0 0.5  1
2  NaN  NaN NaN NaN  5
3  NaN  3.0   0   2  4
```

I've tried using [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to fill only the next NaN to a valid value to 0 and to then linear interpolate the whole dataframe.
The problem I'm facing here is that specifying a value and a limit with fillna won't affect consecutive NaNs, but limit the total amount of columns to be filled.

If possible please only suggest solutions without iterating over each row manually since I'm working with large dataframes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't the `NaN`'s in row 2 get interpolated?

Comment: It gets tricky. Do you need to worry about cases where you could interpolate twice? If you had something like `[1 NaN 3 NaN 5]` what happens there, and what happens when the gap is a single NaN like `[NaN 2 2  NaN 0]`?

Comment: Single NaN gaps are really unusual and can be treated as whatever the easier option is

Comment: @QuangHoang I thought of only interpolating and not extrapolating values. But extrapolation would also be okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a method that will work to replace 0 for the first `NaN` after a valid number and then will interpolate row-wise. I added extra rows in the end to illustrate the behavior for multiple fillings on the same row, fillings of only one value, or rows that end in NaN streaks.

#### Sample Data

```
     A    B   C   D  E
0  NaN  2.0 NaN NaN  0
1  3.0  4.0 NaN NaN  1
2  NaN  NaN NaN NaN  5
3  NaN  3.0 NaN NaN  4
4  3   NaN  7  NaN   5
5  NaN  4   7  NaN   6
6  NaN  4   7  NaN  NaN
7  5   NaN  5  NaN  NaN
```

#### Code

```
m = (df.notnull().cummax(axis=1) & df.isnull()).astype(int).diff(axis=1).fillna(0)
update = m.where(m.eq(1) & m.loc[:, ::-1].cummin(axis=1).eq(-1)).replace(1, 0)

df.update(update)  # Add in 0s

df = df.interpolate(axis=1, limit_area='inside')
```

---

```
     A    B    C    D    E
0  NaN  2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  3.0  4.0  0.0  0.5  1.0
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  5.0
3  NaN  3.0  0.0  2.0  4.0
4  3.0  0.0  7.0  0.0  5.0
5  NaN  4.0  7.0  0.0  6.0
6  NaN  4.0  7.0  NaN  NaN
7  5.0  0.0  5.0  NaN  NaN
```

---

How it works:

```
(df.notnull().cummax(1) & df.isnull())  # True for streaks of null after non-null
#       A      B      C      D      E
#0  False  False   True   True  False
#1  False  False   True   True  False
#2  False  False  False  False  False
#3  False  False   True   True  False
#4  False   True  False   True  False
#5  False  False  False   True  False
#6  False  False  False   True   True
#7  False   True  False   True   True

# Taking the diff then allows you to find only the first NaN after any non-null.
# I.e. flagged by `1`
(df.notnull().cummax(1) & df.isnull()).astype(int).diff(axis=1).fillna(0)
#     A    B    C    D    E
#0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0 -1.0
#1  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0 -1.0
#2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
#3  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0 -1.0
#4  0.0  1.0 -1.0  1.0 -1.0
#5  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0 -1.0
#6  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
#7  0.0  1.0 -1.0  1.0  0.0

# The update DataFrame is a like-indexed DF with 0s where they get filled.
# The reversed cummin ensures fills only if there's a non-null value after the 0.
m.where(m.eq(1) & m.loc[:, ::-1].cummin(1).eq(-1)).replace(1, 0)
#    A    B    C    D   E
#0 NaN  NaN  0.0  NaN NaN
#1 NaN  NaN  0.0  NaN NaN
#2 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
#3 NaN  NaN  0.0  NaN NaN
#4 NaN  0.0  NaN  0.0 NaN
#5 NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0 NaN
#6 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
#7 NaN  0.0  NaN  NaN NaN
```